# MySQL one-to-many relationship

Tags: php, mysql, relational-database

For a forum-like website that I'm building, I have PHP classes 'user' and 'post'. A user has an array of posts. How to resemble that connection in a relational database? With a foreign key on 'post', pointing to a 'user'? This makes sense to me because of a one-to-one relationship, whereas 'user' to 'post' would be one-to-many, and so far as I can see. Any thoughts are welcome - thanks!

Comment: For me yes, a post have only one user, so an foreign key user_id in post seem to be a good idea.

Comment: All right, since that one was so easy, here's a bonus question (link will suffice): How to make that connection in PHP then?

Comment: You only have to do a SELECT post.title,... FROM post WHERE user_id=<an id_user>. After construct posts objects with the query result, save this objects "posts" on collection (so an array in PHP) attribute "posts" in your user class. It's all, you have an OO system :). Up if it's help.

Comment: +1 for that comment. And you answered what would have been my next question: Does it make sense to create any objects in PHP when using a RDBMS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is good. I can't see any better option.

Comment: we agree for this solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Just for clarify;

Now, with OOP, the goal is to work with objects.

So first step is to create object from database. If you want to go further, you can use an ORM and create your DAO. With this layer, you can manipulate object, modify them and finally save them into database with OOP approach. An exemple, Doctrine2 : [Doctrine website](http://www.doctrine-project.org/)

Now, for simple projet you do not absolutely need ORM. Just take care to work with object, and, for exemple, create little method in your object: save(...) who Insert in DB your object.

Complexify it by adding update, delete,... and finally go on CRUD system.
I think it's good idea before go directly on ORM, and see you to learn and concept good OO project.

Hope it's will help you (and sorry for my very bad english :) )